# Category / sub-category loop for drop down menu

Tags: loops, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm trying to dynamically populate a drop down menu with categories and subcategories from a database table. My problem is that I can't figure out a way to loop through the subcategories so they display under the correct category.

In my SQL database I have a table called 'Categories' with 3 columns: id, category, subcategory. The subcategories in the subcategory column are separated by 3 colon marks (Artists:::Childcare:::Classes:::Event).

I'm using unordered lists in html to populate the drop down menu.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">button</a>
<ul>

<?php 

while($allCategories=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultre1)){ ?>

<li><a href="#"><div class="whatever"<?php print      
$relanguage_tags[$allCategories['category']];?> 
<?php if(in_array($relanguage_tags[$allCategories['category']],$reCategory)) 
print "selected='selected'"; ?> >
<?php print $relanguage_tags[$allCategories['category']]; ?></div></a> 

<?php } ?>

<ul>

<?php 
 if($ptype=="showOnMap" || $ptype=="viewFullListing" || $ptype=="home" || $ptype==""){
$reCategoryString=getCommaStringFromArray($reCategory);
$reqr2="select * from $categoryTable where id like '%' ".getRealValue($reCategoryString,"reCategory");
$resultre2=mysql_query($reqr2);
?>

<?php 

while($allSubCategories=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultre2)){ 
$subCatList=explode(":::",$allSubCategories['subcategories']);
$subCatSize=sizeof($subCatList);
for($i=0;$i<$subCatSize;$i++){

?>

<li><a href="#"><div class="whatever"<?php print $relanguage_tags[$subCatList[$i]];?>' 
<?php if(in_array($relanguage_tags[$subCatList[$i]],$reSubcategory)) print   "selected='selected'"; ?> ><?php print $relanguage_tags[$subCatList[$i]]; ?></div></a></li>
<?php }

} ?>

<?php } ?>



         </ul>
        </li> 
 </ul>
</li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$subCatList=explode(":::",$allSubCategories['subcategories']);
$subCatSize=count($subCatList);
for($i=0;$i<$subCatSize;$i++){
      echo "<li>".$subCatList[$i]."</li>";
?>
```

if this isn't the answer means I didn't understood your question well.

**EDIT**

Make a function that shows all the subcategories from a category table:

```
function subCategories($category){ 
     $subCategories="";
      while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from ".$category.""))){
         $subCategories.="<li>".$r['subCategory']."</li>";
      }
     return $subCategories;
}
```

and call this function like this `echo subCategories("Housing");` in each category tag.
Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the response, the code you posted would give me the same output. Sorry my question wasn't very clear. In my SQL database I have a table called 'Categories' with 3 columns: id, category, subcategory. The code I posted displays all my categories correctly but the problem is that each category displays all of the subcategories in the entire table. I need to find a way to separate the subcategories for each category row in my database table. It's a logic problem, I can't figure out how to call subcategories but category. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I don't understand want are you trying to do.Categories and subcategories ... what's the point of this menu?

Comment: This will be a navigation menu for a product browser. The problem is that no matter which category I scroll over, the same subcategories are shown. All the subcategories in my database table are show when I scroll over, Community, personal, housing, etc. http://i50.tinypic.com/2sbsvb9.png

Comment: thanks for the response I just say it today, will try it out soon :P